# Open file viewer (PDF) from iOS application

Tags: ios, pdf, ios4, openfiledialog

We have a code to download a PDF from the server using a SOAP protocol.

We store the file on the Documents folder of the iOs device, and the we want to allow the user to open the file (usually PDF's files)

But, at least on the simulator, the application didn't open the file successfully.

Of course, I can open manually the file (in order to check that the file has been downloaded perfectly)

```
// Get the documents folder where write the content
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:documentDownloaded.fileName];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self getFileCompletePath]]){
    NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self getFileCompletePath]];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: url];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not supported application to open the file %@", filePath);
    }

    [url release];
    [filePath release];
}
```

The file full path in the simulator is:

/Users/User/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/87800296-2917-4F26-B864-B20069336D1D/Documents/0000907.pdf

Anybody knows if is something wrong?

The file could be and spreadsheet, pdf, image, document ... but for the first work around will be great just for pdf's.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open file URLs with `UIApplication`'s `openURL:` method. Because of sandboxing, other apps could not access any files within your application's Documents folder.

You need to use `UIDocumentInteractionController` to open documents that you download or create in other applications.

Comment: Yesterday I was reading about this component on the apple library, I will check today, but ... If I'm not wrong when I apply this code lines ...

// Get the documents folder where write the content
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

I'm accessing to the user documents folder, not to the application document folder.

Answer (score 4):

omz you was right. The final solution was the next.

My controller implemented the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

When the user wants to open the document the code was the next:

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [self getFileCompletePath]];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController = [self setupControllerWithURL:url 
                                                                         usingDelegate:self];

    [documentController retain];
    [documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.frame inView:self.view animated:YES];
    [url release];
    [filePath release];
```

Using the next method, you could found it on the apple developer library

```
- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) 
    setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL *) fileURL
    usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
      [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];
    interactionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;

    return interactionController;
}
```

Finally we include the delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark methods for the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

- (void)previewDocumentWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    UIDocumentInteractionController* preview = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    preview.delegate = self;
    [preview presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    [preview retain];
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [controller autorelease];
}

- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
    return self;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
    return self.view.frame;
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller{
    return self.view;
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: Is there anyway to define the mimetype if say your content is a bytestream and not a file ? Seems silly to write the file to disk with the correct extension if you already have it in memory. The UIWebView supports this when using LoadData.